# Visualizing a State Tree

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arccatalog, versioning, state-tree

I'm running ArcGIS 10.2.1 and I *need* a way to visualize the state tree for my versioned SQL 2012 database.

I've previously used the GDBT tools but there isn't an option available from ESRI that will install on a 10.2.* set up.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'm not a big fan of hacking my registry or uninstalling/re-installing my way back to 10.0 - So far those are the only options I've found for using GDBT.

I'm hoping there are some other utilities or extensions out there that will help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GDBT` is still the best tool out there. Yes it is a registry hack to install in releases past 10.0 but it is one registry entry and does not affect  existing installations. The `GDBT` installer is hard coded to  look for version 10.0 and all the hack does is to direct the install to your `ArcMap` location. So add to this to your registry and you are good to go.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ESRI\Desktop10.0]
"InstallDir"="C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.3\\\\"
```